# plans on creating relational tables in MySQL when importing data from xml file

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here's a sample xml file which I'm planning to import into mysql.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ShipmentRequest>
   <Message>
      <Header>
      <MemberId>MID-0000001</MemberId>    
      <MemberName>Bruce</MemberName>
      <DeliveryId>0000001</DeliveryId>
      <OrderNumber>ON-000000001</OrderNumber>
      <ShipToName>Alan</ShipToName>
      <ShipToZip>123-4567</ShipToZip>
      <ShipToStreet>West</ShipToStreet>
      <ShipToCity>Seatle</ShipToCity>
       <Payments>
        <PayType>Credit Card</PayType>
        <Amount>20</Amount>
      </Payments>
      <Payments>
        <PayType>Points</PayType>
        <Amount>22</Amount>
      </Payments>
      <PayType />
      </Header>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>3.1</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>A-0000001</ItemId>
      <Description>Apple</Description>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <UnitCost>5</UnitCost>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>4.1</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>P-0000001</ItemId>
      <Description>Peach</Description>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <UnitCost>6</UnitCost>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>5.1</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>O-0000001</ItemId>
      <Description>Orange</Description>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <UnitCost>4</UnitCost>
    </Line>
  </Message>
</ShipmentRequest>
```

If I would use mongodb database I would import this file as one record in the collection, but, as I'm going to deal with MySQL, I think it would be best if I import and split the information in the xml file into different tables:

**Table 1: Orders**. This table would contain information about:

1. MemberId
2. MemberName
3. DeliveryId
4. **OrderNumber** - this will have a unique value
5. ShipToName
6. ShipToZip
7. ShipToStreet
8. ShipToCity
9. PayType1 - in this case, Credit Card
10. PayType1amount
11. PayType2 - second payment type, Points
12. PayType2amount

**Table 2: Details**. This will contain information about purchased products. In this case they're three: apple, peach and orange. This table will contain such information as:

1. ItemId
2. Description
3. UnitCost
4. Quantity
5. **OrderNumber**

I think these 2 tables would have a relation via OrderNumber key. If I'm not mistaken, OrderNumber will be called as foreign key for the table 2.

Another idea is to use **OrderNumber** as primary key when importing into a table 1, because it will have a unique value, instead of using incremental primary key.

My question is do you think the way I'm planing to split information in the xml file is the best way? Or please advice if there's a better way. I'm totally new to MySQL and this is my first project.

I didn't tag with "xml" this post, because the question is not about on how to import xml into mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're intending on doing something with this data after it's in your database, and so I would recommend you normalise the design a bit more. I would design it as follows:

```
Member(MemberID, MemberName)
Order(OrderNumber, MemberID, DeliveryID, ShipToName, ShipToZip, ShipToStreet, ShipToCity, PayType1, PayType1Amount, PayType2, PayType2Amount)
Item(ItemID, Description)
Detail(OrderNumber, ItemID, UnitCost, Quantity)
```

where

`MemberID` is the primary key in `Member`, `OrderNumber` and `MemberID` is the primary key in `Order`, `ItemID` is the primary key in `Item`, and `OrderNumber` and `ItemID` are the primary key in `Detail`.

There would need to the corresponding constraints placed between these as well.